# How to display client's custom subdomain in the address bar?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, subdomain

Let's say I have an online service for webmasters at `example.com`. My service presents a web app to be used by the visitors to the websites owned by my webmaster clients. The web app lives at `mywidget.example.com`. Clients can create links to `mywidget.example.com` so their visitors can use the web app.

However, some clients will want to use their own custom subdomain to get to the web app. So, they can create a CNAME such as `widget.clientdomain.tld` and point it to `mywidget.example.com`. That works fine except visitors still see `mywidget.example.com` in the browser address bar instead of `widget.clientdomain.tld`.

What do I need to do to get client custom subdomains to appear in the visitor's address bar instead of `mywidget.example.com`?

Comment: Your customers would just simply create a CNAME record in their DNS that points widget.clientdomain.com to mywidget.acmewidgets.com.

Comment: Thanks, @closetnoc. I checked again and found a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once your clients point the subdomains at your service, you need to configure your web server to use their subdomain rather than your own.  You could use this rewrite rule in *.htaccess* to ensure that only the client subdomain will appear in the address bar.   Other host names pointed to the service (including your own subdomain) will redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^widget\.clientdomain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://wiget.clientdomain.tld/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I ended up placing the files that support the service in an AWS S3 bucket and then allow clients to access those files via CloudFront. A new client can create a CNAME record for their custom subdomain and point it to my CloudFront distribution. I then add that subdomain the CloudFront distribution's list of "alternate domain names". At that point, the service's files can be accessed via the client's subdomain and that subdomain is what appears in the browser's address bar.